# Cliffordness of the qutrit Hadamard gate

Tags: quantum-gate, linear-algebra, quantum-state

Consider a simple generalization of the Hadamard gate to qutrits, defined as follows.

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0\\  
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} &0 \\
  0 &0&1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

It is well known that the two qubit Hadamard gate is a Clifford gate. Is the above gate also a Clifford gate? I could not verify if so.

Comment: So do you consider a general Pauli group here or something? Since, normally, isn't Clifford group define to be the normalizer of the Pauli group?  which is in dim of power of 2.

Comment: The Pauli group can be defined for any dimension; same for the Clifford group. Since the OP mentions "qutrit" in the title (not qubit) I think the setting is meant to be dim=3.

Comment: Yes, the setting is dimension 3.

Comment: why do you call this a generalization of the Hadamard gate? It doesn't really have many (if any) properties in common with it, aside from it having the form $H\oplus (1)$

Comment: It behaves like the Hadamard gate for $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$. The terminology is borrowed from this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.5485.pdf (Section II).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is no. Define

```
X=[[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[1,0,0]]
Z=[[1,0,0],[0,w,0],[0,0,w^2]], w^3=1
```

Then the Pauli group is generated by X and Z and is of order 27.
With H being your matrix, you can check that H'XH and H'ZH are not
in the group.

Calculations like this are easy to do in [gap](http://www.gap-system.org/)

The dim=3 counterpart of the Hadamard gate is the 3 dimensional Fourier transform matrix.